# Problemas no IIS Windows Server

Tags: windows, iis, servidor, iis-7

Postei no outro site da rede StackExchange (SuperUser) em inglês, pedindo ajuda quanto a meu problema, porém ninguém conseguiu resolver. Não sei se posso postar este tipo de pergunta aqui, porém se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato.

Depois de uma atualizaçã meu Windows Server 2008 R2 passou a enfrentar problemas com o IIS (versão 7).

Sempre que eu tento iniciar o IIS me apresenta a mensagem "Não foi possível iniciar devido a grupo de dependência", sempre algo assim. Eu chequei todos os serviços dependentes e nada.

Segue a imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao tentar iniciar o serviço dependente eu recebo erros como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observações:

- Não posso realizar a restauração do sistema, devido a grande
  quantidade de arquivos e programas que serão perdidos.
- Problema apareceu somente após atualizar, o IIS funciona corretamente antes.
- Atualização de rotina.
- Já reinstalei o IIS diversas vezes.
- Já removi, renomeei a pasta "inetpub" várias vezes, e reinstalei.
- Já tentei iniciar individualmente ou parar serviços dependentes, porém dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Tiago, não sei se sua pergunta será tratada como fora do escopo, mas você já tentou reverter a atualização com problema? Já verificou o que diz o Event Viewer ?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, já verifiquei, porém os erros são os mesmos da captura acima. Deixei um pouco de lado essa questão por tentar inúmeras vezes resolver este problema e sem êxito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siga estes passos para solucionar o problema:

1. Vá no **Gerenciador de Servidores** digite para pesquisar no menu iniciar.
2. Abra a aba: **Funções >> Remover funções** e remova todas as funções relacionadas ao IIS/Servidor Web.
3. Após excluir será necessário reiniciar o servidor. Reinicie.
4. Depois novamente no painel **funções** clique em **Remover Serviços de Função**, remova também tudo que se relaciona com o IIS/Servidor Web, FTP, qualquer coisa do tipo, se necessário remova também o servidor DNS, caso você utilize.
5. **Reinicie** e **reinstale** todos os itens.

Comment: Parabéns por ter encontrado a resposta por si só. Editei para ficar melhor organizada. Recomendo que poste-a no SU também

Comment: Opa tranquilo, achei a resposta já faz algum tempo, porém resolvi compartilhar pra ajudar outras pessoas!